# Running EC2 - ELK from browser

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I followed this guide to install ELK on an EC2 instance: https://logz.io/learn/complete-guide-elk-stack/#installing-elk

Now what I'm trying to do is to view Kibana, for example, on my browser since EC2 doesn't have a GUI; it's all a CLI.

Now what should I change in the Kibana and/or Elasticsearch config files to allow this to happen? As Kibana is on port 5601, how can I see it from the browser like this?

```
ec2-x-xx-xx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:5601
```

Whenever I put the above in the browser, nothing happens. I tried to change the `network.host` field to the public IP of the EC2 instance, but that didn't help. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

**Updating answer based on comment thread**

Looking through the guide you linked, a few things are missing:

1. Bind Kibana to an externally accessible port. In `/etc/kibana/kibana.yml`:

```
server.host: "<your private EC2 ip>"
```

2. Add port 5601 to your security group

   The rule will look like this if you want it accessible to the world (though I'd recommend you select the "My IP" option from Source if you don't enable security):
   [image]

Once you've done those things, then you, you can hit Kibana using the public IP/DNS for your EC2 instance like `http://ec2-IP.aws.com:5601`

Comment: Thank you mike, i had allowed all TCP port ranges, but i then changed it to what you had up there, yet still the problem persists. when i try to curl localhost:5601 on my ec2 terminal which has kibana and es i just get nothing in return its like the function runs fine with no errors but nothing shows up

Comment: i see that my browser keeps redirecting my http request to https for some reason

Comment: Can you curl elasticsearch at localhost:9200? Also, what do the Kibana logs say?

Comment: i can curl es at localhost:9200 fine with no errors and how can i find the kibana logs in the terminal? cuz the kibana file i have which is located at /etc/kibana only has 1 file which is the kibana.yml file?

Comment: i checked the network traffic in developer tools and for some reason i keep getting redirected to https internally, does kibana do that by default?

Comment: i cant because there is an internal redirect to https that happens everytime i try that.

Comment: you have TLS enabled?

Comment: not to my knowledge, i haven't touched the config files accept as you instructed. how can i check?

Comment: nvm apaprently f**** chrome was saving the cache and thats why it kept redirecting, on firefox it was workign fine, thank you so much tho man!

Comment: Should the kibana.yml file be bound to the private EC2 IP if the EC2 has a public IP? Which IP should we use in that case?